# Macau/China visa - Being an Indian resident, can i travel Macau on Chinese single entry visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, macau

So, I am travelling to China this month and I had applied for a 2 entry visa to the consulate which they denied for some reasons. This alters my plans to travel to Hongkong and Macau. I just need a small information about visa regulations if anyone is aware of. So, it goes like this, "I want to visit Macau, but turns out I have been awarded single entry visa . Although, I had checked that Indians do not require any visa to visit Macau but does it mean that even if I am allowed free entry to Macau or on arrival entry to Macau, coming back to China means second entry? Because if it's so then I might get caught up in immigration issues. I would like to mention that my flights are back and forth from China and I can't alter that travel route. Which means I cannot leave China, but the main confusion I am into is relating if Macau doesn't need visa does it mean that Chinese visa would suffice?"

I would be very glad if I can get some answers along with some references to either official websites or someone's experiences.

Kindly, help as I am finding this visa stuff in China a little confusing.

Regards,
Pratik

Comment: Please don't write "visa" in all caps.  It is distracting and incorrect.  It is all the more baffling in light of the lack of capitalization of *I, Indians,* and *China,* which *are* supposed to be capitalized.

Comment: Do you get a PAR visa?

Comment: Does this help? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138556/visiting-mainland-china-via-hong-kong-and-macau-on-a-single-entry-visa?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this discussion](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g664891-i12409-k8958425-o10-Macau_Visa_for_Indian_Citizens-Macau.html):

> If you have a HK visit visa, then it depends upon if your visa is single entry or multiple entry. If multiple entry, you should be fine. If single entry, then you should plan for Macau at the end of your trip, so that you can plan to fly out of Macau international airport, or take the ferry from Macau to Skypier at HK International Airport for your outgoing flight so that you don't need to go through HK immigration again

Assuming you did not get a PAR (pre arrival registration) visa, you will need a multi-entry visa (which you did not obtain unfortunately!).

You should adjust your travel plans accordingly. If you want to visit Macau, you can, but you cannot re-enter Hong Kong, so maybe travel to Macau at the end of your HK trip and return to India from Macau.